# Slick Slider не переключает слайды, если их мало

Tags: javascript, html5, вёрстка, slider, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На сайте есть Slick Slider с функцией Slider Syncing, то есть, когда два слайдера синхронизированные и при переключении слайдов одного из них, переключаются одновременно слайды другого.

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
 slidesToShow: 1,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 arrows: false,
 fade: true,
 asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});

$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

Но когда у слайдера .slider-for слайдов меньше, чем указано в параметре slidesToShow, то при клике на его слайды не работает переключение слайдов слайдера .slider-nav — верхнего, который большой. (количество слайдов в обоих слайдерах всегда делал одинаковое)

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, подключил другую версию слайдера, там этой проблемы нет

Comment: >Решил вопрос, подключил другую версию слайдера, там этой проблемы нет подскажи, пожалуйста, в какой версии этой проблемы нет?

Comment: Та у меня старая версия плагина была, в новой версии, которая на оф. сайте, такой проблемы нет